# ProxyPassMatch backreference issues

Tags: regex, apache2, mod-proxy

I am attempting to take all requests matching the regex `^/(map/maps/[^/]*/live/.*)` redirect into a local server http://127.0.0.1:8100/. However, the path that needs to be passed to the backreference differs from the request. Such as the request would be `www.website.com/map/maps/example/live/data`, and the backreference needs to direct to `/maps/example/live/data`. I've tried `ProxyPassMatch ^/(map/maps/[^/]*/live/.*) http://127.0.0.1:8100/$1` but that seems to redirect incorrectly.

Comment: `ProxyPassMatch ^/map/(maps/[^/]*/live/.*) http://127.0.0.1:8100/$1` perhaps (note repositioned `(`)

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the reply! I've tested what you've provided and it still doesn't seem to Proxy the information from whats hosted on http://127.0.0.1:8100/.